# angularJS change color of cell on table (made with ng-repeat)

Tags: html, angularjs, html-table, background-color

I've got this code

```
<body>
<table border = 1>
        <tr>
            <td>Art</td>
            <td ng-repeat="x in books0" ng-click="clicked(0, x.name)">{{x.name}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Science</td>
            <td ng-repeat="x in books1" ng-click="clicked(1, x.name)">{{x.name}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sport</td>
            <td ng-repeat="x in books2" ng-click="clicked(2, x.name)">{{x.name}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Literature</td>
            <td ng-repeat="x in books3" ng-click="clicked(3, x.name)">{{x.name}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table><br>
    <input type = "button" value = "logout" ng-click="logout()">
</body>
```

and I want to change the color of the cell to red if the book has been checked out using angular js. How would I go about changing the color?

Comment: use `ng-style` directive

Comment: You can use `ng-class` or `ng-style`. but i think createion of table via `ng-repeat` is wrong.can you share more about `books` object?

Answer (score 0):

You could use ng-class and refactor your function.

```
ng-class="{true: 'redColorClass', false:''}[x.isClicked === true]"
```

and in your controller

```
$scope.clicked = function(the_number, x) {
   x.isClicked = x.isClicked == true? false:true;
   // and the rest of your code then.
}
```

and change the click into your html to `click(the_number, x)`

so you give the whole book object to your function.

This way every time you trigger `click` function you toggle the attribute isClicked from true to false and the opposite. When it is true, the element gets the redColorClass which is a class you defined in your .css file, and makes whatever you like e.g. `color:red`

Also, your ng-repeat is not the optimal. Try to avoid many ng-repeats, maybe you could do it another way.